# Do i need to create Database Adapter for each database table in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create two tables for my app,
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "books"; and
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "accounts";

how to put two tables in 
public `DataBaseHelper` (Context `context`) {
        super(`ctx`,DATA_BASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

if i can put 1 database name only in `databasehelper`. do i need to create `databasehelper` individually for each table? thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to create an `SQLiteOpenHelper` to each table. With one `SQLiteDatabase` object you can create multiple tables.

There are plenty of examples here on Stack Overflow on how to create a simple database in Android.

But make sure you read the documentation first. See [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for a start.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you want to, but you really don't need to create more than one. One helper would suffice.

You can just call the SQL commands of creating the tables in the onCreate part of the Database helper that you have created see example below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    /*
    *  execute database query to create jobs table
    * */
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_JOB_ORDER_TABLE);

    /*
    *  execute database query to create accounts table
    * */
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ACCOUNT_ORDER_TABLE);

     /*
    *  execute database query to create attachments table
    * */
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ATTACHMENTS_TABLE);

     /*
    *  execute database query to create questions table
    * */
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);

     /*
    *  execute database query to create stages table
    * */
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_STAGES_TABLE);
}
```

You will see that I am creating multiple tables above.